# SQL Server / MySQL / Access - speeding up inserting many rows in an inefficient manner

Tags: mysql, sql-server, ms-access

**SETUP**

I have to insert a couple million rows in either SQL Server 2000/2005, MySQL, or Access.  Unfortunately I don't have an easy way to use bulk insert or BCP or any of the other ways that a normal human would go about this.  The inserts will happen on one particular database but that code needs to be db agnostic -- so I can't do bulk copy, or SELECT INTO, or BCP.  I can however run specific queries before and after the inserts, depending on which database I'm importing to.

eg.

```
If IsSqlServer() Then
    DisableTransactionLogging();
ElseIf IsMySQL() Then
    DisableMySQLIndices();
End If

... do inserts ...

If IsSqlServer() Then
    EnableTransactionLogging();
ElseIf IsMySQL() Then
    EnableMySQLIndices();
End If
```

**QUESTION**

Are there any interesting things I can do to SQL Server that might speed up these inserts?

For example, is there a command I could issue to tell SQL Server, "Hey, don't bother recording these transactions in the transaction log".

Or maybe I could say, "Hey, I have a million rows coming in, so don't update your index until I'm totally finished".

```
ALTER INDEX [IX_TableIndex] ON Table DISABLE
     ... inserts
ALTER INDEX [IX_TableIndex] ON Table REBUILD
```

(Note: Above index disable only works on 2005, not 2000.  Bonus points if you know a way to do this on 2000).

What about MySQL, and Access?

Comment: Are you using an API or a command-line tool or what? Why or in what way do you "not have an easy way to use bulk insert or BCP or any of the other ways that a normal human would go about this"?

Comment: It turns out my INSERTS have to be db agnostic, so it has to work with MySQL, SQL Server 2000 and Access.  But I can do some database specific tweaks before and after the inserts to speed things up.  So I can't completely rewrite the insert to do bulk insert.

Comment: If it has to be db agnostic, then maybe you should update the title and tags to be more accurate regarding your exact situation.

Comment: When you say "has to work with ... Access" do you mean you're *programming* in Access, or that you want to append the data to a Jet database (which is the default data store for Access)? There's a difference, of course, as Access is a development environment while Jet is the database engine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The single biggest thing that will kill performance here is the fact that (it sounds like) you're executing a million different INSERTs against the DB. Each INSERT is treated as a single operation. If you can do this as a single operation, then you will almost certainly have a huge performance improvement.

Both MySQL and SQL Server support 'selects' of constant expressions without a table name, so this should work as one statement:

```
INSERT INTO MyTable(ID, name)
SELECT 1, 'Fred'
UNION ALL SELECT 2, 'Wilma'
UNION ALL SELECT 3, 'Barney'
UNION ALL SELECT 4, 'Betty'
```

It's not clear to me if Access supports that, not having Access available. HOWEVER, Access does support constants in a SELECT, as far as I can tell, and you can coerce the above into ANSI SQL-92 (which should be supported by all 3 engines; it's about as close to 'DB agnostic' as you'll get) by just adding

```
FROM OneRowTable
```

to the end of every individual SELECT, where 'OneRowTable' is a table with just one row of dummy data.

This should let you insert a million rows of data in much much less than a million INSERT statements -- and things like index reshuffling will be done once, rather than a million times. You may have much less need for other optimisations after that.

Answer (score 2):

is this a regular process or a one time event?

I have, in the past, just scripted out the current indexes, dropped them, inserted the rows, then just re-add the indexes.

The SQL Management Studio can script out the indexes from the right click menus...

Answer (score 1):

For SQL Server:

1. You can set the recovery model to "Simple", so your transaction log will be kept small. Do not forget to set back afterwards.
2. Disabling the indexes is actually a good idea. This will work on SQL 2005, not on SQL Server 2000.

   alter index [INDEX_NAME] on [TABLE_NAME] disable

And to enable

```
alter index [INDEX_NAME] on [TABLE_NAME] rebuild
```

And then just insert the rows one by one. You have to be patient, but at least it is somewhat faster.

Comment: Unless you are doing log shipping, in which case you probably don't want to set the recovery model to simple, unless you want to lose some data.

Answer (score 1):

If it is a one-time thing (or it happens often enough to justify automating this), also considering dropping/disabling all indexes, and then adding/reenabling them again when the insert it done

Comment: Wasn't it mentioned in his question that he could not use bulk insert?

Comment: It wasn't mentioned in his question at the time when I wrote this answer. He added that after he saw this.

Answer (score 0):

The trouble with setting the recovery model to simple is that it affects any other users entering data at the same time and thus will amke thier changes unrecoverable.

Samre thing with disabling the indexes, this disables for everyone and may make the database run slower than a slug.

Suggest you run the import in batches.

Comment: I actually control this, so no one else will be using the db at this time.

Answer (score 0):

If this is not something that needs to be read terribly quickly, you can do an ["Insert Delayed"](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/insert-delayed.html) into the table on MySQL.  This allows your code to continue running without having to wait for the insert to actually happen.  This does have some limitations, but if your primary concern is to get the program to finish quickly, this may help.  Be warned that there is a nice long list of situations where this may not act as expected.  Check [the docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/insert-delayed.html).

I do not know if this functionality works for Access or MS SQL, though.

Comment: Has been deprecated and is not longer working in 5.7.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using the Factory pattern?  I'm guessing you're writing the code for this, so if using the factory pattern you could code up a factory that returned a concrete "IDataInserter" type class that would do the work for.

This would still allow you to be data agnostic and get the fastest method for each type of database.

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server 2000/2005, MySQL, and Access can all load directly from a tab / cr text file they just have different commands to do it.  If you've got the case statement to determine which DB you're importing into just figure out their preference for importing a text file.

Comment: Using SSIS or DTS in SQL would standardize the text file load process and take that variable among the destination systems out of the mix.

Answer (score 0):

Can you use DTS (2000) or SSIS (2005) to build a package to do this? DTS and SSIS can both pull from the same source and pipe out to the different potential destinations. Go for SSIS if you can. There's a lot of good, fast technology in there along with functionality to embed the IsSQLServer, IsMySQL, etc. logic.

Answer (score 0):

It's worth considering [breaking your inserts into smaller batches](http://database-programmer.blogspot.com/2008/06/database-performance-1-huge-inserts.html); a single transaction with lots of queries will be slow.

Answer (score -1):

You might consider using SQL's bulk-logged recovery model during your bulk insert.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190422(SQL.90).aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190203(SQL.90).aspx

You might also disable the indexes on the target table during your inserts.